# OpenLDAP meta backend with different directory structure

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I am working on a project and we need to "combine" two completely different Active Directory (AD) servers to one. I have found that OpenLDAP might provide a solution by providing a reverse proxy with the meta backend. However, as the documentation for this backend is incomplete and the tutorials and guides are fairly old I am not certain if this works.

My question is if it is possible for me to combine the following two active directory servers into a new one where both servers have a completely different naming context.

Server 1: dc=container,dc=aws-2,dc=myamazingcompany,dc=local

Server 2: OU=Amsterdam,OU=NL,OU=Employees,DC=myamazingcompany,DC=com

These two servers should merge into the following naming context:

New server: dc=mycompany,dc=com

Is this somehow possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? I wrote [this article](https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2010-02-16-merging-directories-with-openl/#set-up-meta-database) way back in 2010 that has an example of using the meta backend; it's a bit dated at this point but perhaps it will provide some ideas.

Comment: Hi Larsks! Thanks for your very informative article. I indeed already followed the instructions you mentioned in your article. Problem with that is that the structures of the servers that I need to "merge" is not even partly identical. The data, which is saved in those servers however is identical. Therefore, my efforts usually end with the error message telling me that the context is not the same and I should make sure that they are (partly) identical. 

My goal is in the end to receive the credentials from one server and the specific groups from another server.